# MySQL group by descending order

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that does not contain a unique column

```
id | fid | ver | dir

1 || 1 || 1 || 3

2 || 2 || 1 || 2

3 || 3 || 1 || 3

4 || 3 || 2 || 3

5 || 4 || 1 || 4

6 || 5 || 1 || 5
```

My question is how can I select the ID of latest fid (based from ver) in dir = 3

I tried `(SELECT`id`FROM`table`WHERE`dir`='3' GROUP BY`fid`ORDER BY`version`)` but it gives me

```
id

1

3
```

which is not the result I want to get. Here is the result I expect to have:

```
id

1

4
```

Comment: And why wouldn't the results be "3, 4"?

Comment: To make long story short, I want to find `id` of distint `fid` with the latest `ver` from dir = '3'. Which means i should get the id of fid (1,3) with versions (1,2) respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id
from myTable t1
where dir = 3
and not exists (
    select 1
    from myTable t2
    where t1.version < t2.version
    and t1.dir = t2.dir
    and t1.fid = t2.fid
)
order by version
```

Comment: This SQL works for me though I changed it to t1.version < t2.version and t1.fid = t2.fid . Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table WHERE dir = '3' GROUP BY fid ORDER BY version
```

Answer (score 0):

Try group by Version instead,

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE dir='3' GROUP BY version
```